# Connecting 2 Windows computers via a router

Tags: laptop, router, connection, wireless-router

**How do you connect 2 computers via a router ?**

I'm using

1. One desktop computer with Windows 7.
2. One Laptop with Windows 7.
3. One Wireless Linksys router.

The purpose really is to interface the two computers to enable multi-player gaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Not sure what exactly you're after, as your question is ambiguous)

Use ethernet cables, with the router in between...

Desktop PC -> Router <- Laptop

[image]

Plug in the ethernet cables between the router and the desktop and laptop, and they will be connected, you will have a Local Area Network where you can transfer files, etc, even without the internet.

Comment: Does it just work out of the box? No configuration required?

Comment: Never tried it personally @ShreyasSatish, but from what I know, it should.  It's worth a shot...

Comment: Sure, will give it a shot.